# Installed ALSA driver on Ubuntu 11.10, now flashplugin doesn't work

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, flash, ubuntu-11.10, alsa

I installed from here -> http://www.stchman.com/tools/alsa/alsa_setup.sh because I was having so much noise from my speakers when the sound wasn't even playing, and I decided to install alsa drivers instead. Now, they are very good - but I've lost the ability to play any flash in any of my browsers.

Running ubuntu 11.10 on 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio
```

Fixed this by making sure pulseaudio was completely removed - I had also tried to change flash, so re-installing flash might be required if anyone else has this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if flashplugin is trying to use pulseaudio device.

[Ubuntu's wiki might be useful](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio)

Comment: Yes that's right, it was pulseaudio prior to the change